# Print module - Send by email issue

Tags: emails

WHile the Printer-friendly and PDF versions work without any issues (that I can see), I am having issues with the Send by email option. The email gets sent but consists of nonesense. Any ideas as to why this might be happening?

Eg.

```
normal; } */ /* * 1. Corrects text resizing oddly in IE6/7 when body font-size is set using em units * http://clagnut.com/blog/348/#c790 * 2. Prevents iOS text size adjust after orientation change, without disabling user zoom * www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201012/controlling_text_size_in_safari_for_ios_without_disabling_user_zoom/ */ html { /* * To use a 14px font size on the page, delete the 16px and 12px declarations. * To use a 12px font size on the page, delete the 16px and 14px declarations. */ /* Use a 12px base font size */ font-size: 75%; /* 16px x 75% = 12px */ /* Use a 14px base font size */ /* font-size: 87.5%; /* 16px x .875 = 14px */ /* Use a 16px base font size */ /*font-size: 100%; /* 1 */ -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* 2 */ -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* 2 */ /* Establish a vertical rhythm. */ line-height: 1.2em; } /* * Instead of relying on the
```

The following settings enable the send by email function to work Site-wide default - DefaultMailSystem HTML Mail module class - HTMLMailSystem Mime Mail module class - DefaultMailSystem

However, the simplenews newsletters don't get sent.

Changing the Site-wide default to HTMLMailSystem instead, makes the newsletter work but then the send by email feature breaks (sends all sort of random stuff)

How should I configure the settings so both the newsletters and send by email features work correctly?

Comment: This to me looks like a bug or an error caused due to misconfiguration. Please specify more details about the configuration of your mailing system (modules used to achieve that) and their configuration.

Comment: Use mime mail module send out emails in HTML format.

Comment: Thank you @NikhilM

I am using mime mail for the print module, but my simplenews module requires html mail module in order to send html emails.

Comment: Thank you @Indrock

The following settings enable the send by email function to work Site-wide default - DefaultMailSystem HTML Mail module class - HTMLMailSystem Mime Mail module class - DefaultMailSystem

However, the simplenews newsletters don't get sent.

Changing the Site-wide default to HTMLMailSystem instead, makes the newsletter work but then the send by email feature breaks (sends all sort of random stuff)

How should I configure the settings so both the newsletters and send by email features work correctly?

Comment: Thank you @develkar

I have now added more details. Hope you are able to shed some light on this.